# Limits of trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, limits

I know my answer is correct, but are my steps correct?

$$
\begin{align}
& \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\tan(2t)}{t}\\[8pt]
& = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \tan(2t)\\[8pt]
& = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(2t)}{t \cdot \cos(2t)} \cdot \frac{2}{2}\\[8pt]
& = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{2 \cdot \sin(2t)}{2t \cdot \cos(2t)}\\[8pt]
& = \lim_{t \to 0} \left(\frac{\sin(2t)}{2t} \cdot \frac{2}{\cos(2t)}\right)\\[8pt]
& = 1 \cdot \frac{2}{1}\\[8pt]
& = 2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Yes indeed! Nice work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're correct by I would have said explicitly something you said only implicitly:
$$
\begin{align}
& \phantom{={}}\lim_{t\to0} \left(\frac{\sin(2t)}{2t}\cdot\frac{2}{\cos(2t)}\right) \\[8pt]
& = \left(\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin(2t)}{2t}\right) \left(\lim_{t\to0} \frac{2}{\cos(2t)}\right)
\end{align}
$$
This works if both of the latter limits exist as finite numbers --- in particular it works if you do not have $0\cdot\infty$.  If you get that, then you can't use that method to find the limit.

Answer (score 1):

you may consider this approach:

- Since $\tan{2t} \sim 2t$ as $2t \to 0$,
- Your limit might be rewritten as follows:

$$L = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\tan{2t}}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{2t}{t} = 2.$$

Cheers!

Comment: You might want to prove the first point.

Comment: Hi @Sawarnik! I guess this could be proved by using the Taylor expansion for $\tan{x}$ about $x = 0$: $$\tan{x} \approx x+\frac{x^3}{3} +\frac{2 x^5}{15}+ \mathcal{O}(x^6),$$ then for $x \ll 1$ you may assume $\tan{x} \approx x$. In addition, I think long polynomial division for the Taylor series of $\sin{x}/\cos{x}$ might be useful here too, taking into account that $\cos{x}=1$ as $x \to 0$. However, I'm not sure if this is sufficient enough to prove my statement in a rigourous way. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes exactly is correct congratulation

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @voldemort: It seems to me it is an Answer, since the literal Question asks if the (working) "steps" are correct.  Of course you may judge it not to be a good Answer.

Comment: @hardmath: well technically you are right- but I would recommend deletion for this post- it doesn't add any value to the site. But of course, opinions differ.

Comment: This would be better as a comment on the question.